# IdentityServer 3 with MemebershipReboot , how to implement Custom Client store

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, membershipreboot

I am exploring the option of using IdentityServer3 along with MembershipReboot as the IdentityManagement solution.

I have managed to download some samples from github and get them working.

Link from where i downloaded the sample :- 
[github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MembershipReboot/WebHost)

But I am not able to get an example of an implementation which is using DB to persist Clients and Scopes and Claims. All the examples i have come across are using InMemory way of storing this info.

Can someone who has done this please help here?

Answer (score 0):

There are many moving parts that are separate that you might be conflating.

Clients and scopes are modeled by the various store extensibility points (docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/serviceFactory.html). There is an EF implementation here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.

Claims for users is modeled with the IUserService extensibility point (docs: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html). If you are using MR as the backing implementation for your IUserService, then there's an implementation here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot.

For all of the above we have different samples to show each one in isolation: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/. It's up to you to merge the various samples that show something in isolation to match the combination you want.

Comment: Brock Allen Thanks. I saw this line of code in the configuration which is doing factory.RegisterConfigurationServices(entityFrameworkServiceOptions); which registers ScopeStore and ClientStore. And while i use the OAuth2 client to call identityserver i get the error which says invalid_client. But I also ran the SQL profiler to see the query getting executed and it returns the client. What could be the problem?

Comment: Enable logging then -- that should tell you more.